# Cannot connect between 2 sequential public IPs

Tags: networking, vpn, ftp

So far I've been unable to find any solution to this, so here I am.
I have 2 different business locations that I am trying to get a connection between with both VPN and FTP.
Both sites are with the same ISP and their public IPs are exactly sequential. xx.xxx.xx.45 and xx.xxx.xx.46

I have FTP servers set up at both locations already, and they are both able to connect in and out to OTHER locations I have. One of these other locations is also on the same ISP (my home), and others are on multiple different ISPs. I just cannot get these specific 2 locations to talk to each other.

Both locations also have VPN services set up that I can connect to from OTHER locations, but not between these 2. One site has a Unifi Security Gateway (USG-3P), the other is a Unifi Dream Machine Pro.

The ISP swears it's nothing on their end (of course :eye roll:), even though just recently one site had no access beyond the first hop outside our building. Even though they swore that wasn't their problem it ended up being a firewall issue of theirs.

Ports are opened correctly at both sites. I can sit at home and connect FTP to either location, and I can sit at either location and connect to FTP at my home.

Any suggestions? Or should I start hounding the ISP at the risk of them trying to bill us $175/hr for a technician to say it wasn't their fault.

Comment: What kind of subnet mask (prefix length) is configured for these IP addresses, on the routers or servers that have them assigned? (It sounds like it's configured wider than it should be; e.g. maybe it is /24 when it should be a /32?)

Answer (score 0):

> Suggestions?

It probably boils down to an ISP support issue.

I *will* just observe that the sequential numbers you mentioned are slightly
unusual. Possibly there's a gotcha that appears in some ACL or routing entry.
Consider `10.0.0.44/30`, which includes `.44`, `.47`,
and addresses for your pair of hosts.
If there's something special about that pair,
I would have tried to assign `10.0.0.44/31` or `10.0.0.46/31` to it.
Summary: double check any potential "netmask length" config issues.

Beyond that, it's just the usual ping + traceroute debugging,
using tools like `$ sudo mtr 10.0.0.45`.
The type of packets (with deliberately low TTL)
that you send to stimulate nearby devices
matters quite a lot.
A router ACL that filters TCP might let ICMPs through just fine,
so send test traffic that looks just like your real production traffic.

Use `$ sudo tcpdump host 10.0.0.46` or similar
to see stimulus traffic arriving at a server's network interface.
Sometimes A & B lack connectivity,
and it turns out that A can send to B just fine
but B lacks a return route, or B sends through
a firewall which discards its return traffic.

Verify that `ifconfig` shows proper netmask,
and that `netstat -rn` shows a proper default route
and a proper more-specific route for your other host.

Write down a network diagram showing network addresses and physical links.
(Your question would have been stronger if you'd included such a diagram.)
Use the diagram to verify connectivity to successively more distant hops.
Share the diagram with your ISP to ensure everyone's working
on solving the same problem.

If hosts and routers have filtering ACLs,
consider temporarily dropping an ACL (replace with "allow all")
and compare the before/after test results.